# jQuery error - datepicker not a function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hi i am hit with this error " **$("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function** " . It was working perfect for me before. However when i opened my application today, its hit with this error. I am not getting where i went wrong. Can somebody help me to solve this. Will paste my code here.

```
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <tr>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id='datepicker' value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</body>
```

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I had copied your code and pasted in Jsfilldle and it worked fine for me... Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/shabirgilkar/Ys4y7/

Comment: then why is it not working for me ?

Comment: is there any other `javascript library` like mootools, prototype, dojo etc... also on same page??

Comment: Maybe your browser can't load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js? from googleapis. Try to move it to your server

Comment: nopes...i am not using any other library..

Comment: still having the same error

Comment: the error in firebug is " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed.. It was a small ignorance from my side. The jqury.js file was referred in another page which was extended from `{% facebook_connect_script %}` . Thanks a lot for you guys help.